# cannot find the declaration of element 'resources'

Tags: resources

Cannot find the declaration of element

This is in values.xml (a system therefore uneditable file) and is giving me
Cannot find the declaration of element 'resources'
This is an error that is preventing my project from building

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you could post a log of the actual error, it should tell you which file and line is causing the issue, and why.

Resources need to be pointed to in order for your project to compile properly and with the correct resources. For example, when coding with java (referring to building for Android) you might see an *import* of a resource directory.

This could look like:

`import com.android.systemui.R;`

or

`import com.android.settings.R;`

The **R** you see there represents a resource directory.

Posting your build error along with the file(s) you modified would be very helpful.